# Split hexagons in half

Tags: modeling, topology

I have a mesh with a lot of hexagons and I need to convert it to quads. The obvious way would be to split each of those hexagons in half. Is there a quick and simple way to do this for all the faces at once? (I already used the cut tool with snapping, but I feel like there is a tool for this in blender and I just don't know where to look for it)
[image]

Comment: Face menu > _Poke_ followed by _Tris to Quads_ quadrifies most of the hexes for me, but leaves some edge-cases, so not a full answer.

Comment: I can't get Tris to quads to work, it creates four edges arranged into an X shape, so that I get two quads and two triangles (I tried adjusting the options, but maybe not enough).

Comment: Hey :). If you only need all quad mesh (e.g. for turbosquid), you can simply apply one level of subdivision and it will turn all the hexagons into quads :).

Comment: Also, for something like this consider using a single shape as base, and grow it with array modifiers. That way you don't have to edit every single hexagon.